# How to import a blazor custom element in another JS application?

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side, custom-element

I have a blazor server app, with a registered custom element as below code:

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor(options =>
{
    options.RootComponents.RegisterAsCustomElement<Counter>("my-blazor-counter");
});
```

I want to import this blazor custom element in another `node.js` application to convert it into a lit element(web component).
I have added below scripts in my node.js app

```
<script src="https://localhost:7075/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script src="https://localhost:7075/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/BlazorCustomElements.js"></script>
```

but while initializing the Blazor it still using node app port and failing while initialization.
I am not sure I am missing anything here or if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: Related with example projects: https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/main/src/BlazorCustomElements

Comment: It does not work as it suppose to be. I have referred this but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The following describes how I resolved an issue similar to yours: trying to register a custom element, the client not rendering the component and no error message anywhere.

I followed [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-custom-elements) but the there was nothing happening client-side. After inspecting the websocket's traffic using Firefox I ran into the following message from the client to the server (slightly edited for readability):

```
ùÀµEndInvokeJSFromDotNetÂÚÙ[
    2,
    false,
    "Could not find 'registerBlazorCustomElement' ('registerBlazorCustomElement' was undefined).
    findFunction/<@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:497
    findFunction@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:465
    E@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:2606
    attachWebRendererInterop/<@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:33097
    attachWebRendererInterop@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:33145
    beginInvokeJSFromDotNet/s<@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3501
    beginInvokeJSFromDotNet@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3475
    _invokeClientMethod/<@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:71894
    _invokeClientMethod@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:71880
    _processIncomingData@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:69922
    kt/this.connection.onreceive@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:64322
    connect/</o.onmessage@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:48638
    EventHandlerNonNull*connect/<@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:48489
    connect@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:48005
    _startTransport@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:57626
    _createTransport@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:56195
    _startInternal@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:54044
    async*start@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:51309
    _startInternal@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:66198
    _startWithStateTransitions@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:65598
    start@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:65262
    Gn@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:129904
    Yn@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:127771
    async*@https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:131523
    @https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:131529
    "
]
```

In my case it was that I hadn't added `<script src="/_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CustomElements/BlazorCustomElements.js"></script>` to the html.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling to get this working for a Blazor serverside app. I created a test.html page in the wwwroot of the blazor project.

The fix for me was to specify the base url.

My html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- my component is here -->
    <blazor-counter></blazor-counter>
    <base href="http://localhost:5144">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, 
I've similar issue and your proposal seems to be related to WebView2. 
I can render correctly the Blazor Browser Custom Element in edge by it does not work in WebView2 unless to add your trick.
Were you using WebView? did you found more information and avoid the trick?

Comment: hi @rlasjunies nope I wasn't using webview just Blazor Serverside